# What does this macro meaning? I copy it from ReactiveCocoa framework

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I like to see framework sourcecode. when I see this framework , I cann't get it .
please help me .

I don't konw  every step at this macro. What does this marco do ?

## define metamacro_concat_(A, B) A ## B

I feel this macro is not objective-c syntax.

thx

```
//
//  Macro.h
//  Macro
//
//  Created by JerryBob on 14-12-11.
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class RACSignal;




/**
 * Returns the number of arguments (up to twenty) provided to the macro. At
 * least one argument must be provided.
 *
 * Inspired by P99: http://p99.gforge.inria.fr
 */
#define metamacro_argcount(...) \
metamacro_at(20, __VA_ARGS__, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

/**
 * Returns the Nth variadic argument (starting from zero). At least
 * N + 1 variadic arguments must be given. N must be between zero and twenty,
 * inclusive.
 */
#define metamacro_at(N, ...) \
metamacro_concat(metamacro_at, N)(__VA_ARGS__)

/**
 * Returns A and B concatenated after full macro expansion.
 */
#define metamacro_concat(A, B) \
metamacro_concat_(A, B)

#define metamacro_concat_(A, B) A ## B


/**************************************************************************/


/* @endcode
*
* This is primarily useful when dealing with indexes and counts in
* metaprogramming.
*/
#define metamacro_if_eq(A, B) \
metamacro_concat(metamacro_if_eq, A)(B)

/**
 * Returns A and B concatenated after full macro expansion.
 */
#define metamacro_concat(A, B) \
metamacro_concat_(A, B)

/********************************start from  here******************************************/
#define RAC(TARGET, ...) \
metamacro_if_eq(1, metamacro_argcount(__VA_ARGS__)) \
(RAC_(TARGET, __VA_ARGS__, nil)) \
(RAC_(TARGET, __VA_ARGS__))

/// Do not use this directly. Use the RAC macro above.
#define RAC_(TARGET, KEYPATH, NILVALUE) \
[[RACSubscriptingAssignmentTrampoline alloc] initWithTarget:(TARGET) nilValue:(NILVALUE)]      [@keypath(TARGET, KEYPATH)]`enter code here`


@interface RACSubscriptingAssignmentTrampoline : NSObject

- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target nilValue:(id)nilValue;
- (void)setObject:(RACSignal *)signal forKeyedSubscript:(NSString *)keyPath;

@end
```

Comment: and this                  /**
 * Returns the Nth variadic argument (starting from zero). At least
 * N + 1 variadic arguments must be given. N must be between zero and twenty,
 * inclusive.
 */
#define metamacro_at(N, ...) \
        metamacro_concat(metamacro_at, N)(__VA_ARGS__)

Answer (score 1):

metamacro_concat takes the value of macro A and macro B and concatenates them

Comment: why it use  "##"   concatenates them ?

Comment: Counts the number of arguments passed to the macro

Comment: thx.       metamacro_concat_(A, B) A ## B   When I use this macro . metamacro_concat_(1,2) why it return 12. When I use this ( int i = 1 ## 2) compile error.